# Genymotion does not connect with Virtual Box Santoku (Lubuntu).It pops an error "Can't create a session.Virtual Host-only adapter"

Tags: linux, genymotion

Host - Windows.

Enabling the Virtual Host-Only adapter in Network Connections does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Genymotion in a virtual machine? Genymotion Desktop does not work in a virtual environment: https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/latest/01_Get_started.html#operating-systems

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same.Thank you for your response.